# Passing navigation into function in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, navigation

Previous developer was passing null for whatever reason which gives:

TypeError: null is not an object evaluating tabNavigation.navigate.

Here is the code:

```
import { NavigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

const renderBackToDashboard = (tabNavigation: any) => {
    return <HeaderBackButton tintColor={defaultOptions.headerTintColor||'white'} labelVisible={defaultOptions.headerBackTitleVisible||false} onPress={() => { tabNavigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAMES.DASHBOARD_TAB); }} />
}

const testViews = (tabNavigation: any, isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREEN_NAMES.LEGAL} component={LegalDisclosure} options={{ title: t('legal'), headerLeft: () => renderBackToDashboard(tabNavigation), headerRight: () => isLoggedIn ? renderLogo(tabNavigation) : null }} />
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREEN_NAMES.DATA} component={DataProtection} options={{ title: t('data'), headerLeft: () => renderBackToDashboard(tabNavigation),  headerRight: () => isLoggedIn ? renderLogo(tabNavigation) : null }} />
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREEN_NAMES.GUEST} component={GUEST} options={{ title: t('guest'), headerLeft: () => renderBackToDashboard(tabNavigation), headerRight: () => isLoggedIn ? renderLogo(tabNavigation) : null }} />
        </>
    );
};

const getLoggedOutScreens = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={defaultOptions}>
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREEN_NAMES.AUTH} component={AuthScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            {testViews(null, false)}
            <Stack.Screen name={SCREEN_NAMES.MY_SCREEN} component={MyScreen} options={{ title: t('myScreen') }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};

return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={NavigationRef} theme={MyTheme}>
        {loggedIn ? getLoggedInScreens() : getLoggedOutScreens()}
        {loggedIn ? <UserErrorComponent /> : null}
    </NavigationContainer>
);
```

**RootNavigation.ts**

```
import React from 'react';

export const NavigationRef = React.createRef<any>();

class Nav {
    navigate = (name: string, params?: any) => {
        NavigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
    };
}

export const RootNavigation = new Nav();
```

I tried : `{testViews(NavigationRef, false)} , {testViews(NavigationRef.current, false)} , {testViews({NavigationRef}, false)}`

Didnt work. I would be glad for any suggestions.

Error is fired at `tabNavigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAMES.DASHBOARD_TAB);`

Comment: Would you please post your code about `testViews()`?

Comment: @kiuQ I added, sorry.

Comment: Since you have already defined RootNavigation, it is not required to pass navigation prop to the navigation stack. All you need to do is using `RootNavigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAMES.DASHBOARD_TAB);`. See [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop#usage).

Comment: Compiler complains: Property 'navigate' does not exist on type 'RefObject<any>'.  with  `NavigationRef.navigate(SCREEN_NAMES.DASHBOARD_TAB);`

Comment: Please also post your code in `RootNavigation.tsx`, maybe you forget to define `navigate()`.

Comment: it is defined, I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Your project navigation structure seems fine. But RootNavigation.ts may need to modify like this.

**RootNavigation.ts**

```
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name: string, params?: any) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}
```

In any screen included in this navigation container, you can use following code to navigate.

```
//Import navigation like this
import * as RootNavigation from './RootNavigation';

const renderBackToDashboard = () => {
  return (
    <HeaderBackButton 
      tintColor={defaultOptions.headerTintColor||'white'} 
      labelVisible={defaultOptions.headerBackTitleVisible||false} 
      onPress={() => { 
        //you can use this line to navigate
        RootNavigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAMES.DASHBOARD_TAB); 
      }} 
    />
  )
}
```

You can see more in react-navigation docs.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/#usage

Answer (score 0):

Change below fixed my error:

```
const testViews = (isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
    const getTestDefaultOptions = ({navigation}: {navigation: any}) => ({
        headerRight: () => isLoggedIn ? renderLogo(navigation) : null
    });

    return (
        <>
            <Stack.Screen
                name={SCREEN_NAMES.LEGAL}
                component={LegalDisclosure}
                options={ (props) => ({
                    ...getTestDefaultOptions(props),
                    title: t('legalDisclosure')
                })} />
            <Stack.Screen
                name={SCREEN_NAMES.DATA}
                component={DataProtection}
                options={ (props) => ({
                    ...getTestDefaultOptions(props),
                    title: t('dataProtection'),
                })} />
            <Stack.Screen
                name={SCREEN_NAMES.GUEST}
                component={GUEST}
                options={ (props) => ({
                    ...getTestDefaultOptions(props),
                    title: t('guest')
                })} />
        </>
    );
};
```